# Trying to concatenate a specific row from multiple XML files into a single file

Tags: xml, import, concatenation, append, gpx

I am trying to create a single file that contains a specific row from a little over 1000 XML (GPX) files. More specifically, I am trying to return row 13, which is the first row that contains GPS locations from multiple files for race events. The XSD for the file is described here: http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd.

I tried importing the files in Excel but that proved to be a quite manual process.

Here's an excerpt from one of the files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx
  version="1.1"
  creator="Runkeeper - http://www.runkeeper.com"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd"
  xmlns:gpxtpx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1">
<trk>
  <name><![CDATA[Running 6/5/18 4:17 pm]]></name>
  <time>2018-06-05T20:17:57Z</time>
<trkseg>
<trkpt lat="45.424648000" lon="-75.716201000"><ele>57.0</ele><time>2018-06-05T20:17:57Z</time></trkpt>
```

I am trying to return the contents of the first `<trkpt></trkpt>` element.

Comment: Do you have experience using PowerQuery?

Steps:

Open Excel and go to the “Data” tab.
Click on “Get Data” and select “From File”.
Choose “From Folder” and select the folder containing your XML files.
Click on “Combine & Transform Data” under the “Combine” menu button.
Select the last node from the left pane.
In the query editor, click on “Add Column” and select “Custom Column”.
In the formula bar, enter Xml.Tables(File.Contents([FullPath])){13} and click OK.
Close and load the query.
This will create a single file that contains row 13 from all of your XML files

Comment: Hi @pcandido! Thank you for your reply. I guess I should be replacing the 'FullPath' in your instructions with the actual path to the folder that contains all the files, correct? When I do so, I get an 'Invalid Identifier' error. The full formula I entered is 
= Xml.Tables(File.Contents([C:\Users\levesqe\Documents\EL\Perso\Excel\Running\gpx])){13}

Does that seem correct syntax? Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, Eric! 
Try the same formula but without the bracket [ ]
So: Xml.Tables(File.Contents("C:\Users\levesqe\Documents\EL\Perso\Excel\Running\gpx")){13}

Comment: Now getting the following error message: Formula.Firewall: Query 'gpx' (step 'Added Custom') references other queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source. Please rebuild this data combination. Any thoughts?

Comment: Delete everything and start again since it is difficult to guide you if you do not have experience in Power Query. There are steps that are created automatically on the right of the interface. It is possible that you have created one of the steps incorrectly and it warns you of possible errors.

Comment: At least paste a text sample of the expected node and the parent one. text, not an image please.

Comment: @LMC I added a sample of the code, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.